# Gradle build failing after updating to Gradle 1.2.2

Tags: java, gradle, stubby4j

I have a java project that utilizes Gradle for testing and building. I recently had to update my JVM to 1.7.0_75 to use Maven for another project for work.

Now I have gone back to my Gradle project, I found that gradle -v was returning command not found, and after I used brew install Gradle, my build script returns the following error:

```
* Where:
Build file '/Users/adamhardie/Documents/Workspace/sagepay-stub/build.gradle' line: 27

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'sagepay-stub'.
> No such property: testReport for class: org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test_Decorated
Possible solutions: testReporter
```

I have confirmed the build.gradle script has not been altered in any way since it was last working, so what could be the possible cause of this error?

Below is the part that seems to be causing issues ( it is the build script for this project: https://github.com/azagniotov/stubby4j )

```
if (project.name != 'main') {
  tasks.withType(Test) {
     Task testTask ->
        def totalSuiteCount = 0
        def successSuiteCount = 0
        testReport = false
        testLogging {
           events /*"passed", */"skipped", "failed"
           exceptionFormat "full"
           showExceptions true
           showCauses true
           showStackTraces true
        }
        doFirst {
           //println ""
           //println "::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::"
           //println ":::::                         Running " + project.name.toUpperCase() + " module tests"
           //println "::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::"
        }
        afterSuite { testDescriptor, testResult ->
           if (testDescriptor.getName().contains("$stubbyProjectGroup")) {
              totalSuiteCount += testResult.getTestCount()
              totalTestCounter += testResult.getTestCount()
              successSuiteCount += testResult.getSuccessfulTestCount()
           }
        }
        doLast {
           println ""
           println "::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::"
           println ":::::                         Ran " + project.name.toUpperCase() + " module tests"
           println "::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::"
           println ":::::                             Passed (" + successSuiteCount + "/" + totalSuiteCount  + ") tests"
           println ":::::               Total tests executed in $stubbyProjectName project so far " + totalTestCounter
           println "::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::"
           println ""
        } 
  }    
}
```

Comment: Has gradle version being used changed?

Comment: i presume so, i had not updated in a while. I am not sure why gradle was removed from my classpath, so i used brew to re install. My current version is 2.2.1 but i am not sure what i was before

Comment: So it seems You've found the reason.

Comment: ok thanks, what would you suggest i do to solve this?  revert to an older version? i dont know why updating would break my build script, is it possible some component has been deprecated?

Comment: There's a hint in error message: `Possible solutions: testReporter`. Probably the component name was changed.

Comment: i did attempt that first , but i am getting another error to do with a boolean value
> Cannot cast object 'false' with class 'java.lang.Boolean' to class 'org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.report.TestReporter'

Comment: Share critical `build.gradle` part.

Comment: updated question with link to full project and sample of build script, thanks for input so far

Comment: As far as I understood your current gradle version is 2.2.1?

Comment: As far as I see You'd like to ignore test report? You previous version must have bean at least 1.12 - see here for deprecation: http://gradle.org/docs/1.12/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/testing/Test.html

Comment: Let me know if it worked. Maybe will add it as an answer.

Comment: It is definitely depreciated, but i have not changed the build script. Instead I downgraded my gradle version to 1.12 in order to complete my work. I will try to alter the script once I have finished and update

Comment: it seems that replacing testReport = false with "reports.html.enabled = false" allows the script to continue, but there are multiple other depreciation errors caused by upgrading to 2.2.1. My issue is resolved though and I am able to build my Jar. Thank you for your help

Comment: May I add it as an answer for your acceptance?

Comment: of course! add and i will accept when i can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that gradle version was changed by accident and thus the problems. `testReport` for `Test` class is deprecated from at least *1.12* version of gradle.

Now reports can be configured via `reports` as stated [here](https://gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/testing/Test.html#reports(groovy.lang.Closure)).

Answer (score 1):

Apologies for replying so late:

[stubby4j](https://stubby4j.com) has been upgraded to use Gradle 7.2 recently. To add more, the current project Gradle config has a standard configuration without any custom add-ons nor hacks.